# Is there a way to view / edit the definition of a computed variable after it has been created?

Tags: spss

I have created some new computed variables in SPSS. I would like to be able to view the definitions (to check for errors) and possibly edit them after the fact. I cannot find a way to do this or find any advice on the internet.

I can see the definitions in the saved syntax file but there does not seem to be a way to pull the definitions up and view them from the SAV file itself.

Note that this is NOT the same thing as recoding a variable - I want to be able to bring up something like the new variable dialog box for an existing computed variable, view the definition and, if necessary, edit it.

Comment: This is a vague question. What exactly do you want to check ? That the 'compute' command worked..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-click on the relevant output in your .SAV file.
Select, copy, and paste the `COMPUTE` statement to a Syntax file.
Edit the `COMPUTE` statement as desired.
Add the command `EXECUTE.` after the `COMPUTE` statement.
Select this block of code.
Click on the 'play' button in the ribbon (or, select Run > Run Selected).

This will recompute the variable.

**CAUTION: When you run `COMPUTE` from syntax, you don't get the warning asking if you want to replace the existing variable.**